# How do I dynamically hide/show a single tab within dojo's tabContainer?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm having some trouble figuring this out.  What I'm trying to have happen is, when a certain condition is met, a tab is showing, when it isn't, the tab is hidden.  I've checked a few answers in similar questions and they've all given pretty much the same response, which is to do either this:

```
dojo.style("tabContainer", "visibility", "visible");
```

However, when I do this, I get the message that `.style` is not a function.  Can anyone explain how I need to go about changing the visibility?

Screenshot of the selected tab within the tabContainer
[image]

**Code**

```
this.tabContainer.getChildren()[0].style("visibility", "visible");
```

Comment: Use `dojo/dom-style` for changing the style attributes of a particular domNode. [See documentation here](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-style.html)

Comment: create fiddle/runnig sample with ur code... that will be better to ans...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of playing with the style, I would rather use the `disabled` attribute of the tab and override the CSS it adds.
Like this:

```js
require([
    "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],

  function(TabContainer, ContentPane) {

    var tabContainer = new TabContainer({}, "tabContainer");
    tabContainer.startup();

    var cp1 = new ContentPane({
      title: "Pane 1",
      content: "Pane 1"
    });
    tabContainer.addChild(cp1);

    var cp2 = new ContentPane({
      title: "Pane 2",
      content: "Pane 2"
    });
    tabContainer.addChild(cp2);


    //make sure you did not selected the tab you are going to hide
    tabContainer.selectChild(cp2);
    //disable the tab. It will be hidden by the css class 'dijitTabDisabled'
    cp1.controlButton.set('disabled', true);

    /*
    Note:
    
    cp1 = tabContainer.getChildren()[0];
    cp2 = tabContainer.getChildren()[1];
    
    so you could write:
    
    tabContainer.selectChild(tabContainer.getChildren()[1]);
    tabContainer.getChildren()[0].controlButton.set('disabled', true);
    
    */

  });
```

```css
.tundra .dijitTabDisabled {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">

<div class="tundra">
  <div id="tabContainer">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use dojo 1.7+, use dojo/dom-style for better practice.

You can hide the tab by adding css to tab.controlButton. Like this:

```
domStyle.set(tab.controlButton.domNode, "visibility", "hidden");
```

Have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/an90dr/ep32anm8/